# Entity framework without unit of work pattern

Tags: entity-framework

Can't we use entity framework without unitof work pattern. What are the advantages and disadvantages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework has unit of work internally implemented you can't simply use it without that. If you load entities and modify them they are not persisted to database until you call `SaveChanges`.

If your question is more about "Should I use custom implementation of unit of work?" the answer depends on many factors. Generally you don't need it. Custom UoW is usually used with repositories. Repositories are in turn sometimes used to hide interaction with EF and make your upper layers persistance ignorant. Another reason for using repositories is better testability of your upper layers. But in my opinion neither of these two patterns is really needed with modern ORM tools.

Comment: Then if we are using repositories then we should use UoW . Is it correct?

Comment: You should share single context among repositories. To achive that we usually use custom unit of work implementation where unit of work hides the context from upper layers but provides it to repositories.